# How to choose user account when multiple user accounts are used by the same person, so the same biometrics (fingerprint, face)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, user-accounts, windows-hello

I want to use windows hello, but due to constrains related to corporate policies, I must have a separate administrator account. This means that I normally use and log in to the standard user and whenever I need to run something with administrative rights, I just write my username and password.

Now I'd like to skip writing a password and use my face to authenticate that it's me. So I set up windows hello for the admin account and it all works great. The problem is that I also want to use windows hello to log in with my standard account.

Is there a way to let windows know that the face registered for the 2 user accounts is the same and to just offer the option of which account to run each time it detects that face?
Same question for fingerprints. Although technically, the easy solution is to just register 2 different fingers for each user account.

Comment: Have you tried configuring Windows Hello for both accounts?  One would typically only have to select the user they want to log into, then choose which authentication method they want to use, at least that has been my experience.  You should verify you are allowed to configure Windows Hello on your Administrator account before you do so though.

Comment: For uac, if I put my fingerprint in, it automatically figures which account is a match, without ever choosing an account, and this is my issue.

Comment: I believe you already gave the most comfortable way of choosing which user to log in as: using one finger for regular user, another finger for admin. Also saves you any additional clicks another system of choosing might need.

Answer (score 5):

After a lot of research I determined that there is no system for this as of this day. Moreover, I discovered that Windows doesn't allow the same biometrics (face or fingerprint) to be used by multiple accounts. If you try to add your face to a second account and it determines that it is the same face, then it doesn't allow you to do it.

I find it a bit concerning, security wise, that an action taken under one user account (setting up face recognition), without administrative rights accesses the credentials of a different user from the same system, but that's a different story.

I found some nice workarounds though.

For fingerprints, as mentioned in the question, I just use my index for the regular account, and the middle finger for the administrative account.
For face recognition, I register my regular looking face for the normal account and my smiling face for the admin account. It works great!

I still prefer to use the fingerprint though because the UAC already activates the fingerprint reader, while the face recognition needs to be activated by pressing `More choices -> Face`

Comment: This is a great idea - thank you!